# calling json file from firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have 3 groups( html ) inside every group is four people and those people are the same in all 3 groups but just different numbers (votes/credits whatever), and I have a json file where is values for those people inside group. My HTML file reads my json file without problem.

I'm using Dialogflows Inline Editor to work with the Google Assistant. What I want is that the same way my html( javascript ) is reading those values from json file, I want to be able to load the `person.json` file as well. I have edited that many times could not manage to call person.json url.

For example:

> "Hey google, tell me Alex credits"
>   < here it should read from my json file which is 73 >

Here are codes: person1.html

```js
    var response = await fetch("laurel.json");
    var arr = await response.json();
    var laurel= arr[1];

            var dflt = {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
           //   donut: true,
              gaugeWidthScale: 1.1,
              counter: true,
              hideInnerShadow: true
            }

            var ee1 = new r({
              id: 'ee1',
              value: laurel['Jennifer'],
              title: 'Jennifer ',
              defaults: dflt
            });

            var ee2 = new r({
              id: 'ee2',
              value: laurel['Peter'],
              title: 'Peter',
              defaults: dflt
            });
         
             var ee3 = new r({
              id: 'ee3',
              value: laurel['Justin'],
              title: 'Justin',
              defaults: dflt
            });
         
             var ee4 = new r({
              id: 'ee4',
              value: laurel['Alex'],
              title: 'Alex',
              defaults: dflt
            });

          });
```

inline editors index.js :

```js
 

 
  intentMap.set('persons1', someFunction);
function someFunction(agent) {
    agent.add(`Alex credits are 73 `);
}
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/tree/master/samples/actions-on-google
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to use this code or tried to make the networking call inside the code? Did you get any errors trying to do this? If you have - updating your question with any further relevant information can help.

Comment: @Prisoner  i need to have firebase function so that i can call person.json url to read values from, just like javascript in html is reading that. I have tried but didnt manage, could you possibly help with this, it should go to my json file and read values for example ”Hi google, tell me alex credits” it should go to json and take alex’s value from there and say ” Alex credits are 73”

Comment: Yes, you said most of that in the question. You say "I have tried but didn't manage". Can you update the question with what you tried? When you tried, were there errors? If so, update the question with the errors. Have you done any research about how to make HTTP calls in node.js?

Comment: Are you using the Spark or Blaze plan? Because you can't make outbound network requests if you're on Spark. (see pricing: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: @DennisAlund for this purpose it should be free of charge ?

Comment: I'm just saying that if you're on the Spark plan **you can't make outbount network requests**. Perhaps that helps to know if you're planning to build that into your fulfillment dependency.

Comment: @DennisAlund How to build this thing and still be free of charge ? What other ways ?

Comment: You can always store the data in Firebase Realtime Database. It's easy to do that if your data is already JSON format. Just import it into the database. The Spark plan still allows you to make network requests to Google APIs, including using the Firebase suite.

Comment: Thats good, could you possibly give also answer to the main question, some implementation which helps me ?

Comment: @DennisAlund  if i use mongodb instead of firebase realtime database, would it be free of charge ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options here. Either you switch your plan to Blaze and make a network request for the JSON data that is hosted on your public URL mentioned earlier.

Or you can also just put the JSON data into the Firebase realtime database as it is also accessible as a JSON document on a public URL if you set the database rules to publicly **readable**.

**database.rules.json**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "persons": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can access your JSON data in Firebase on this URL: `https://<your-project-id>.firebaseio.com/persons.json`

That should be effectively the same thing for accessing in your web app.

For your AoG fulfillment you can simply use the Firebase SDK to access the data

`firebase.database().ref('persons').child('personId');`

Comment: Thank you for good information which will help me, but could you also possibly help me with , need some nodejs implementation which reads from that json and takes into account ’intents’

Comment: Your original question contains a statement that is reading a JSON document. By implementing that you're already good on your way.

As for taking "intents into account" that's more of "how to develop for AoG" and it's moving out of the scope for the question.